# Duplication of business logic in queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-applications, domain-driven-design

In the project I am working on, I have `DebtCollectionCase` object which contains `Invoices, Payments, CreditNotes`, etc... The problem I encounter is that number of queries is rising all the time, and it will continue to rise and I have a lot of repetition of some calculations in those queries. For instance, calculation to get `UnpaidAmount` or `Interest`. It is already a mess, and it will get worse with time.

The solution would be to put those calcuations in Domain Objects, in functions, which then can be reused in every place, but for that to be done I need to fetch whole aggregate in memory, which means `DebtCollectionCase, Invoices, Payments, CreditNotes` should be fetched and then just call functions to do the calculations. It should be OK for a single record, but what when I need a list of those, a hundread of DebtCollection cases with their Invoices and Payments. It would be a big amount of data fetched and it could affect performances.

So it is a question of doing in memory calculations which is better for reusability and maintance and putting bussines logic in queries, which means better performance but harder for maintance and violating DRY. Does anyone have any advice which approach I should use?

Comment: Most probably your domain design is bad. More specifically, it seems `DebtCollectionCase` "aggregate" is definitely too big and doesn't really reflect your business invariants. So, I would start from re-thinking your model. If you still think it's ok (or you can't change it), I would go for special "projection" read-only model, which is backed by database efficient queries (repository pattern might be ok for you). Please, let me know if I understood your problem.

Comment: There is a third option, which is to cache the resulting calculations in properties and store these in the DB. The complex part of it now becomes to make sure the property gets recalculated when certain part of the state changes which could be complex in itself (reactive programming techniques could be helpful), but it allows to keep the business logic in the domain while keeping queries simple and efficient.

Comment: I found a solution, it is called DelegateDecompiler. It lets u use entity unmapped properties and functions in the linq Select and Where statements, which means they are reuseable, and are translated to SQL, so I dont need to fetch entities in memory. Here is the link if someone needs https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler.

Comment: @Aleksa That is pretty cool. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, it is called `DelegateDecompiler`. It lets u use entity unmapped properties and functions in the linq Select and Where statements, which means they are reuseable, and are translated to SQL, so I dont need to fetch entities in memory. Here is the link if someone needs [Link to DelegateDecompiler](http://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler).